# R assign product type to user based on group by count results

Tags: r, dplyr

Data set is online purchase information based online market place example (ebay, amazon).

```
user_id, product_code, bought_date, time_spent, store_id, product_type, refurbished, unqiue_visit_id
001, e.12, 20120102, 104, 101, computer, yes, 1010
002, e.24, 20120201, 100, 101, infant-dress, no, 2001
003, s.32, 20130302, 230, 101, shoes, no, 2121
004, y.23, 20130404, 212, 103, computer, yes, 2422
005, s.43, 20130803, 104, 101, laptop, yes, 2342
001, a.12, 20120202, 104, 101, computer, yes, 1011
002, b.24, 20120201, 100, 101, infant-dress, no, 2001
003, c.32, 20130302, 230, 101, shoes, no, 2122
004, e.23, 20130404, 212, 103, computer, yes, 2424
005, f.43, 20130803, 104, 101, laptop, yes, 2340
001, g.12, 20120102, 104, 101, computer, yes, 1013
002, h.24, 20120201, 100, 101, infant-dress, no, 2031
003, l.32, 20130302, 230, 101, shoes, no, 2000
004, m.23, 20130404, 212, 103, computer, yes, 1422
005, d.43, 20130803, 104, 101, laptop, yes, 1142
001, d.12, 20120102, 104, 101, desk, yes, 1110
002, f.24, 20120201, 100, 101, glass, no, 1111
003, n.32, 20130302, 230, 101, liquid, no, 2021
004, t.23, 20130404, 212, 103, liquid, yes, 22
005, u.43, 20130803, 104, 101, dress, yes, 2942
001, d.12, 20120102, 104, 101, desk, yes, 1910
002, f.24, 20120201, 100, 101, glass, no, 2901
003, n.32, 20130302, 230, 101, liquid, no, 2921
004, t.23, 20130404, 212, 103, liquid, yes, 2922
005, u.43, 20130803, 104, 101, dress, yes, 2942
001, kk.12, 20120103, 105, 101, desk, yes, 410
003, n.32, 20130303, 230, 101, liquid, no, 2621
```

`unique_visit_id` created using the `user_id`,`product_code`,`store_id`, `product_type` and `bought_date`

Goal is to first get a unique visit counts by grouping `user_id` and `product_type`

```
test.visits <- test %>% 
  group_by(user_id,product_type) %>% 
  summarize(visit_count = n_distinct(unqiue_visit_id)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(visit_count),user_id)


   user_id product_type    visit_count
     <int> <fct>           <int>
 1       1 " computer"         3
 2       1 " desk"             3
 3       2 " infant-dress"     3
 4       3 " liquid"           3
 5       3 " shoes"            3
 6       4 " computer"         3
 7       5 " laptop"           3
 8       2 " glass"            2
 9       4 " liquid"           2
10       5 " dress"            2
```

now I want to assign the product type to the user based on highest number of visits. If there are equal visits by recency (`bought_date`), `refurbish`, last value of the `store id`.

```
example:
     1       1 " computer"         3
     2       1 " desk"             3
```

basically condition to tie break. Highest number of visits product_type get assigned to the user within group

Comment: You want to `arrange` the rows based on `visit_count` and break the ties based on `bought_date` ?

Comment: yes but if bought date is same check refurbish (yes trumps no) and if that also same last value of `store_id`, at the end user get assigned to one `product_type`